# Json object not parsing correctly

Tags: jquery, json

I have [this page](http://kodiakgroup.com/clients.php) where toward the bottom you can click on the different categories to parse the applicable companies' logos. The last item in the array (The 'Wesco' logo) is only supposed to appear in the "Distribution" category but appears in several categories. The json file reads:

```
{"customers": [
        {"customerName": "3M", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-3m.jpg", "category": "healthcare,manufacturing","link":"http://www.3m.com"},
        {"customerName": "Acxiom", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-acxiom.jpg", "category": "info-tech,services","link":"http://www.acxiom.com"},
        {"customerName": "Adobe", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-adobe.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"http://www.adobe.com"},
        {"customerName": "Alcatel-lucent", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-alcatel.jpg", "category": "telecommunications,info-tech","link":"http://www.alcatel-lucent.com"},
        {"customerName": "Amdocs", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-amdocs.jpg", "category": "info-tech,services","link":"http://www.amdocs.com"},
        {"customerName": "Arris", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-arris.jpg", "category": "info-tech,manufacturing","link":"http://www.arrisi.com"},
        {"customerName": "Aspect", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-aspect.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"http://www.aspect.com"},
        {"customerName": "Berylhealth", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-beryl.jpg", "category": "healthcare","link":"http://www.berylhealth.com"},
        {"customerName": "Bisys", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-bisys.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"www.citibank.com"},
        {"customerName": "Broadview Networks", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-broadview.jpg", "category": "telecommunications","link":"http://www.broadviewnet.com"},
        {"customerName": "Butler Schein", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-butler.jpg", "category": "info-tech,healthcare,distribution","link":"http://www.butlerschein.com"},
        {"customerName": "Carlton-Bates", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-cbc.jpg", "category": "info-tech,distribution","link":"https://www.carltonbates.com"},
        {"customerName": "Cisco", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-cisco.jpg", "category": "info-tech,manufacturing","link":"http://www.cisco.com"},
        {"customerName": "Citrix", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-citrix.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"http://www.citrix.com"},
        {"customerName": "Comverse", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-comverse.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"http://www.comverse.com"},
        {"customerName": "Convergys", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-convergys.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"http://www.convergys.com"},
        {"customerName": "Cypress Communications", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-cypress.jpg", "category": "telecommunications","link":"http://www.cypresscommunications.net"},
        {"customerName": "Deloitte", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-deloitte.jpg", "category": "services","link":"http://www.deloitte.com"},
        {"customerName": "Ecova", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-ecova.jpg", "category": "services","link":"http://www.ecova.com"},
        {"customerName": "Gartner", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-gartner.jpg", "category": "services","link":"http://www.gartner.com"},
        {"customerName": "GE Healthcare", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-ge.jpg", "category": "healthcare,info-tech,manufacturing","link":"http://www.gehealthcare.com"},
        {"customerName": "Henry Schein", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-henry.jpg", "category": "info-tech,healthcare,distribution","link":"http://www.henryschein.com"},
        {"customerName": "HP", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-hp.jpg", "category": "info-tech,services","link":"http://www.hp.com"},
        {"customerName": "Infor", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-infor.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"http://www.infor.com"},
        {"customerName": "Intuit", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-intuit.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"http://www.intuit.com"},
        {"customerName": "Ixia", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-ixia.jpg", "category": "info-tech,manufacturing","link":"http://www.ixiacom.com"},
        {"customerName": "Jack Henry", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-jack.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"http://www.jackhenry.com"},
        {"customerName": "Marconi", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-marconi.jpg", "category": "telecommunications,info-tech","link":"#"},
        {"customerName": "McKesson", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-mckesson.jpg", "category": "healthcare,info-tech","link":"http://www.mckesson.com"},
        {"customerName": "Mmodal", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-mmodal.jpg", "category": "info-tech,healthcare","link":"http://mmodal.com"},
        {"customerName": "Motorola", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-motorola.jpg", "category": "info-tech,manufacturing","link":"http://www.motorola.com"},
        {"customerName": "Nihon Kohden", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-nihon.jpg", "category": "healthcare,manufacturing","link":"http://www.nihonkohden.com"},
        {"customerName": "Owens and Minor", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-om.jpg", "category": "healthcare,distribution","link":"http://www.owens-minor.com"},
        {"customerName": "Paetec", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-paltec.jpg", "category": "telecommunications","link":"http://www.paetec.com"},
        {"customerName": "Polyvision", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-polyvision.jpg", "category": "telecommunications,manufacturing,distribution","link":"http://polyvision.com"},
        {"customerName": "Q2ebanking", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-q2.jpg", "category": "info-tech","link":"http://q2ebanking.com"},
        {"customerName": "Rubbermaid", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-rubbermaid.jpg", "category": "info-tech,healthcare,manufacturing","link":"http://www.rubbermaid.com"},
        {"customerName": "Wesco", "imageLink": "/images/client-logos/logo-wesco.jpg", "category": "distribution","link":"http://www.wesco.com"}

    ]
}
```

The jquery is:

```
$.getJSON('customers.json', function(data) {
                for(var index in definedCategoryArray){ //cycle through categories array
                    for(var i=0; i<data.customers.length; i++){ //cycle through json data
                        if (definedCategoryArray[index]==true){//if the value in the array is true (item checked)
                            console.log(data.customers[i].customerName+ ' : ' + data.customers[i].category);
                                if(data.customers[i].category.indexOf(',') != -1) //if there is more than one category, detect the comma seperating them
                                    categoriesPlural = data.customers[i].category.split(',');   
                                else //there is only one category
                                    categoriesPlural[0]=data.customers[i].category;
                                for (var y = 0; y<categoriesPlural.length; y++){
                                        //console.log(categoriesPlural[y]);
                                        if(categoriesPlural[y] == index){ //match category (from definedCategoryArray index) to items in json object to parse
                                            $('ul#customers').append('<li class="' +data.customers[i].customerName.replace(/\s+/g, '-') + '" id="'+data.customers[i].customerName.replace(/\s+/g, '-')+'"><a href="'+ data.customers[i].link +'" title="'+ data.customers[i].customerName +'" target="_blank"><img src="'+ data.customers[i].imageLink +'" alt="'+ data.customers[i].customerName +'" /></a></li>');
                                            checkDuplicates(data.customers[i].customerName.replace(/\s+/g, '-'));
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).fail(function() { console.log( "error" ); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are multiple categories you are assigning categoriesPlural with an entirely new set of elements, but if there is only one category you are only modifying the first element of categoriesPlural, so anything previously assigned to categoriesPlural (except the first element) will still be there.

Instead of `categoriesPlural[0]=data.customers[i].category` you should do `categoriesPlural=[data.customers[i].category]`

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring or resetting `categoriesPlural`. When there is only one item after the `.split()`, you are sticking this one item in `categoriesPlural[0]`, but `categoriesPlural[1]` will then still hold its value from the previous iteration. Declaring `categoriesPlural` at the start of your loop will do the trick:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.customers.length; i++) {

  var categoriesPlural = [];
  ... // More of your code
```

Comment: I didn't try this implementation because the above worked for me, but thank you sooo much for the help!

Comment: No worries, I think @winterblood's implementation is more elegant anyway, it does exactly the same but with less lines of code.